# Tensorflow progress bar really broken

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to train a model and look at it's progress, but the progress bar in the console just look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b076y.jpg

i dont know why those extra symbols are there or how to remove them, please help!

Comment: This would happen if you look at the progress bar without a terminal, like for example redirecting output to a text file. More information is needed on how exactly you get this output.

Comment: this is just the output in the IDLE console, created by keras

Comment: Use a real terminal to see if the problem happens there

Comment: alright, can do

Comment: it doesn't do it in CMD, so it must be a setting in IDLE that got changed somehow, the question is, what setting????